# Maximum number of characteristics in Bluetooth LE

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

So we have a problem with a project of ours.

We started a Bluetooth LE project, and made a list of UUID's and services.

We develop on a bluegiga chip, which is capable of holding like 100 private characteristics.

Unfortunately the other party (hardware side) has chosen another chip. Now we are on a go for a few months and the hardware side just noticed it chose a chip with a maximum of 10 characteristics.

So here we are, an almost finished app and an incompatible chip.

So we are trying to look for a solution.

There are three ways we can come up with:

- Reprogram the app so it can handle more values per characteristic
- Cut functionality
- Choose a chip which is able to hold 100 characteristics

The second one isn't really an option. But we are trying to understand what to do now.

So before we proceed we would like to know which option you think is the best way to choose. We would advice choosing another chip, but if people think 10 characteristics should be max we have to reprogram.

Please tell us what you think of the situation. It would be great of help.

Comment: You need to be clear if your trying to be compliant with some profile or profiles or doing everything yourself so can spec whatever you want.  Clearly if your working with defined profiles your options are limited.  Either way you have a big hit on your project.  Estimate the software rework cost (If possible) and the hardware re-work cost for a start.

Comment: You may want to pay some attention to the distinction between a chip vs firmware.  Characteristics may only exist at the software level of the latter.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the nature of the 100 characteristics. If you could logically group them together, also taking into account their access properties (Read and/or Write) and their sizes, you could come up with only 10 characteristics with long values (up to 512 bytes).

Then you may use Read Blob Requests and Prepare/Execute Write Requests as you wish to read/write only parts of these long characteristics (which logically represent separate data for your application).